# Python - Sort XML derived from CSV by original CSV field names

Tags: python, xml, sorting, csv

I've derived XML from a CSV file.  I'm having an issue ensuring the XML is sorted in the same order as the CSV header.  The issue is that DictReader is not maintaining the sorting, however, if I use `fieldnames` I then run into the issue that `'str' object has no attribute 'items'`.

My CSV file has the following content:

```
FieldA,FieldB,FieldC,FieldD
1,asdf,2,ghjk
3,qwer,4,yuio
5,slslkd,,aldkjslkj
```

And my Python script is as follows:

```
    import gzip
    import csv
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring

    csv_file = 'Workbook1.csv.gz'

    class GZipCSVReader:
        def __init__(self, filename):
            self.gzfile = gzip.open(filename)
            self.reader = csv.DictReader(self.gzfile)
            self.fieldnames = self.reader.fieldnames

        def next(self):
            return self.reader.next()

        def close(self):
            self.gzfile.close()

        def __iter__(self):
            return self.reader.__iter__()


    def to_xml(r):
        for row in r.fieldnames:
            element = Element('event') # parent element is required
            children = [] # reset the list with each new row

            # Iterate through key:value pairs for each row and create a sub-element
            for (k, v) in row.items():
                if v:
                    sub = SubElement(element, k) # adds the column header as the sub
                    sub.text = v # adds row value as sub-element text

            # Create a list of sub-elements, minus the parent.
            for child in list(element):
                children.append(tostring(child))
            event_data = ''.join(children) # this creates a string of data to be passed to the server
            print (event_data + '\n')
        r.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = GZipCSVReader(csv_file)
    to_xml(r)
```

The above code prints out each CSV row as XML SubElements.  If you notice, the order of the SubElements is different from the CSV header, and if I try `fieldnames` I get the error `'str' object has no attribute 'items'`.  Is there a way around this so I can have the resulting XML in the same order as the CSV header?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code , how you are using fieldnames

Comment: I mean show us the code where you are using the field name along with the line you are getting the error from

Comment: Yeah, realized that was a fail haha.  Question updated.

Comment: Added an answer, what you are doing for fieldnames is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrongly , when you do - `for row in r.fieldnames` - `row` is actually the `fieldname` , not elements.

What you need to do is iterate over `r` , and for each row in r , iterate over the fieldnames, and then get `row[fieldname]` as value and `fieldname` as key and create the sub element.

Example function -

```
def to_xml(r):
        for row in r:
            element = Element('event') # parent element is required
            children = [] # reset the list with each new row

            # Iterate through key:value pairs for each row and create a sub-element
            for k in r.fieldnames:
                v = row[k]
                if v:
                    sub = SubElement(element, k) # adds the column header as the sub
                    sub.text = v # adds row value as sub-element text

            # Create a list of sub-elements, minus the parent.
            for child in list(element):
                children.append(tostring(child))
            event_data = ''.join(children) # this creates a string of data to be passed to the server
            print (event_data + '\n')
        r.close()
```

Comment: That makes sense, and fixed the issue.  Thanks for the explanation.  That wasn't clear to me from reading the docs and my logic process.